# How to split on unicode whitespace in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, unicode

In Kotlin if we use:

```
string.split(Regex("\\s+"))
```

Then we can split a string into words separated by whitespace. However the string:

```
val string = "a\u2000b"
```

doesn't split since the regex doesn't match unicode whitespace characters.

I there a way to split the string on all whitespace characters?

Comment: You may want to take a look at icu4j (http://site.icu-project.org/home/why-use-icu4j) , specifically at: `BreakIterator.getCharacterInstance()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used the following regex to match Unicode whitespace:

```
Regex("[\\p{javaWhitespace}\u00A0\u2007\u202F]+")
```

This works because while `\s` matches only Latin-1 whitespace, `\p{javaWhitespace}` matches everything for which `Character.isWhitespace()` is true.  For some reason, this doesn't include a few particular characters, which I've listed separately.

More info in the docs for [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Related fact: although [java.lang.String.trim()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()) doesn't remove non-breaking spaces or figure spaces, [kotlin.String.trim()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/trim.html) does!

Comment: Hang on a sec, actually, that's not correct since "\u2000b" is actually interpreted as "\u2000" + "b" which is the 'EN QUAD' space character followed by the letter 'b'. I've reverted the question to its original form as this is what I intended.

Comment: Ah yes, in Java/Kotlin you'd probably need to represent U+2000B as a surrogate pair…  In any case, I'd already edited my answer to remove that irrelevancy, so we're just confusing everyone else now :-)

Answer (score 4):

Since Java 7 [`Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) allows to specify the [`UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS)-flag which would basically also work for your current issue:

```
Pattern.compile("\\s+", Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS)
```

Unfortunately this isn't directly supported via [`RegexOption`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-regex-option/index.html) with Kotlins [`Regex`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-regex/index.html) yet. There is a [known issue that also describes a workaround (KT-21094)](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-21094):

```
string.split("""(?U)\s+""".toRegex())
```

You (most probably) require Java 7+ for that to actually work. Alternatives could be to use other predefined character classes instead. However, you need to lookup the appropriate `Pattern`-javadoc for your Java version to ensure that it is actually working (or do it in a trial-error-manner ;-)).