# Why regex does not remove non word symbol?

Tags: android, kotlin

There is function `clearName` that remove special symbols from string.

Lets we have string `Voilà - Therapy`. If run `clearName` in [kotlin playground](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#)
output is `voil therapy` (as excepted). But if run in android app output is `voilà therapy`. Why and how to fix? Or is there way to translate `à` to `a` in order to dont remote it?

```
// kotlin playground
fun main() = runBlocking<Unit> {
    println("Voilà - Therapy".clearName()) // voil therapy
}

fun String.clearName(): String {
    return this.lowercase()
        .replace("""\W""".toRegex(), " ") // non-word character to space
        .replace("""\s{2,}""".toRegex(), " ") // two space in row to one space
        .trim()
}
```

Comment: I think your problem is the local settings in the android device, try to add  this.lowercase(Locale.ROOT)

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer about unicode whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56236932/1431750) - As a workaround to not being able to use the `Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS`-flag with `RegexOption`, you need to use the `(?U)` modifier to indicate unicode for regexes. (Otherwise, `à` is treated as "non-word" and gets replaced with a space.)

```kotlin
fun String.clearName(): String {
    return this.lowercase()
        .replace("""(?U)\W""".toRegex(), " ") // non-word character to space
        .replace("""(?U)\s{2,}""".toRegex(), " ") // two OR MORE spaces to one space
        .trim()
}
```

[Output, and Kotlin playground](https://pl.kotl.in/tYBep0TK6):

```
voilà therapy
```